# Set, get data from class by pointer (not by index)

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to save and get data in class B by pointer. Class A is information object, class B is EXTRA information about A. I dont want to use index as parameter so can i use object adress for class B to get extra information about object A in this adress ?

Code explanation:

```
class A;
class B;// B is countainer that stores ages.

A* a;
B b;
int main() {
    a = new A();
    b.setAge(a, 26);//give adress and age
    cout << b.getAge(a) << endl;//get age saved in B by object A adress
    b.delete(a);
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

How to make setAge and getAge realizations, what variables need to add to class B ? Maybe class B should be like table there first column is adresses and second column is age. Can I make it directly like array[index] ?

Comment: I don´t understand what you want (maybe add the classes...), but a `delete` is missing. And no, missing `delete`´s are not ok.

Comment: You may be interested by `std::map<const A*, int>`.

Comment: `void main` is wrong.

Comment: Yes, probably I should use maps, because I want bind adress with information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use `std::map`

```
class Person {};
class AgeMap
{
public:
    void setAge(const Person& person, unsigned age) { ages[&person] = age; }
    unsigned getAge(const Person& person) const { return ages.at(&person); }

private:
    std::map<const Person*, unsigned> ages;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    Person alice;
    Person bob;
    Person charlie;
    AgeMap ages;

    ages.setAge(alice, 36);
    ages.setAge(bob, 42);
    std::cout << ages.getAge(alice) << std::endl; // 36
    std::cout << ages.getAge(bob) << std::endl; // 42
    try {
        std::cout << ages.getAge(charlie) << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception&) {
        std::cerr << "no age provided for Charlie\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Kk5FBu)

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to store not only age in AgeMap i should use several maps or map<const Person*, STRUCT_NAME> ages ?

Comment: @Vinigas: It depends if some `person` may have `age` with `name` info (if yes, several maps is a good option), but a unique map with custom struct as value seems more appropriate in general case.